# What is Kant's opinion on gossip?

Tags: kant, society, language, deontology

Just curious this evening what Kant and other, contemporary, deontologists say about gossip. I don't mean deliberate lies, but a certain attitude to truth and truth telling in which both the repercussions of what we say about others and the egocentric levity of our pretences - based presumably in wanting to seem knowledgable or even wise, worth listening to, despite excluding (gossip is often behind ones back) our subject matter and their desires, due to an epistemic vice similar to self deceit but with only an intersubjective intent - are treated too casually.

I'm guessing that you should not assume that your own low standards of proof and reasons to believe are necessarily shared by others, who you are gossiping about as much as to.

Comment: This article talks about Kants view on gossip. https://open.library.okstate.edu/introphilosophy/chapter/kantian-ethics/  It may be useful.  To summarize, it is your duty not to gossip if you have given your word to keep it secret or were told in confidence. We do this for good will

Comment: They disagree, at least in emphasis, "*notwithstanding its valuable relational and social functions, it is wrongful, at least in some of its forms*", [Fabre](https://philpapers.org/rec/FABTMO-9). "*I then look at reasons, mainly utilitarian, for declaring all such talk to be morally acceptable. I argue that these are not sufficient, either individually or collectively... but they do bring out the many positive aspects of gossip that are often overlooked.*"  [Westacott](https://philpapers.org/rec/WESTEO-5). And both invoke Kant.

Comment: In case it's not in the essay that @IdiosyncraticSoul linked to: Kant peculiarly supported alcohol use when it could lubricate social discourse in the sense of making people more directly honest, IIRC. Not behind-their-backs backtalk, then, but straight talk, straight up. My apologies if that comes off like a wack poem :P

Comment: You just want opinion in your title question? In philosophy perhaps one should not gossip opinion...

Comment: Apparently, Kant had rules about being a host and guest of a dinner party: https://curiouslionlearning.com/how-to-host-a-dinner-party-and-save-society/#:~:text=Kant%20said%20there%20was%20a,trust%20and%20encourage%20open%20conversation. To summarize: What is said at a dinner party stays at the dinner party.

Comment: i don't see how what you are implying makes any sense @DoubleKnot all opinions are gossip? all questions about opinions are gossip? doesn't make any sense whatsoever